# angular vs reactJs is there a state as well

Tags: angular, jhipster

I want to do a small angular project with jhipster.

one question before I start.

Is there something similar to the react state in jhipster and angular?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Behavior Subjects for global state, or `@Input` and `@Output` to manage local states. I'd highly recommend running through the Tour of Heroes tutorial before beginning any project: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular components have mutable states, which are component class instances themselves (`this`). While component input and output properties are mutable too, they play roughly same roles as React props.

Due to differences in lifecycle Angular doesn't need `setState`. Change detection in component templates relies on Zone.js, and RxJS observables are conventionally used to handle state changes in component classes.

As for state management, [`angular-redux`](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) or [`ngrx`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) can be used for state management to introduce familiar Redux patterns and benefits to Angular development. So can [`mobx-angular`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angular).